# Alternate MKLocalSearchCompleter in iOS 9.0 location search

Tags: ios, swift, geocoding

I found `MKLocalSearchCompleter` is only available in `iOS 9.3+`, unfortunately my application needs to support up to `9.0+`. I want to make a auto complete suggestions for location search in `Swift 4.0.` What are the alternatives of `MKLocalSearchCompleter`?

Is there any other better way to show auto suggested locations?

***What have been tried:***

I have used `CLGeocoder, geocodeAddressString()` but its not possible to use for auto completion search because changes in the search string is frequent so the api calls as well, which is not allowed by the API. What am I missing?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete have you considered using a Google Places API for this?

Comment: @Pasichnyk i need something different as i already mentioned in the bounty description

Comment: Your manager must be new to iOS platform. Why even bother support iOS 9.0? If you want, switch to min sdk 9.3 and nothing will change, as the device OS segmentation is not even close to android. Check this - https://www.statista.com/statistics/565270/apple-devices-ios-version-share-worldwide/

Comment: And also, check this https://data.apteligent.com/ios/, can't see the reason for you to support such outdated version and not having the ability to use the latest features. Just communicate this with your managers, show him the facts and he wii most probably agree, that you can support min sdk 9.3, just find the way to deliver this information to him.